# Xuggler: add only arch‑i686‑w64‑mingw32 jar

Tags: java, maven, applet, dependency-management, xuggler

I'm using Xuggler 5.4 in my applet, including it into the project with Maven (it has too many dependences to be included directly with .jar file). Here is a part from my pom.xml.

```
<repositories>
    <repository> <!--Xuggler repo-->
        <id>xuggle repo</id>
        <url>http://xuggle.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/repo/share/java/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>
    <dependency> <!--Xuggler dependency-->
        <groupId>xuggle</groupId>
        <artifactId>xuggle-xuggler</artifactId>
        <version>5.4</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

It's not a secret, that this library's size is rather big (near 40mb). Nevertheless, there are some special libs on Xuggler's [downloads page](http://www.xuggle.com/downloads). For example xuggle‑xuggler‑arch‑i686‑w64‑mingw32.jar is suitable only for 32-bit Win PC's, but it is much more smaller then universal library.
The problem is, I don't know how to include this .jar into a project with Maven (I'm very new with it).

Neither

```
<artifactId>xuggle‑xuggler‑arch‑i686‑w64‑mingw32.jar</artifactId>
<version>5.4</version>
```

Nor

```
<artifactId>xuggle‑xuggler</artifactId>
<version>arch‑i686‑w64‑mingw32</version>
```

Gives no result.

What I'm doing wrong?